# Keeping track of label bindings

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a simplified version of a Twitter app I'm working on. 
Using this setup, how can I keep track of which "Retweet" label the user clicked?

I want the retweet function to return with the "Id" of either "Tweet1" "Tweet2" or "Tweet3", depending on which "Retweet" label the user clicks on.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class GetTweet:

    def __init__(self):

        self.tweet_list = []
        self.tweet1 = {"id": 1, "text": "tweet1"}
        self.tweet2 = {"id": 2, "text": "tweet2"}
        self.tweet3 = {"id": 3, "text": "tweet3"}
        self.tweet_list.extend([self.tweet1, self.tweet2, self.tweet3])


class Widgets:

    def __init__(self):

        self.label_list = []
        self.tweet_text_var = []

        x = 0
        for n in range(0, 6, 2):

            self.tweet_text_var.append(tk.StringVar())
            self.tweet_text = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=self.tweet_text_var[x])
            self.tweet_text.grid(column=0, row=n)
            self.label_list.append(object)
            self.label_list[x] = ttk.Label(text="Retweet", cursor="hand2")
            self.label_list[x].grid(column=0, row=n+1)
            self.label_list[x].bind("<Button-1>", retweet)

            x += 1


class PopulateVariables:

    def __init__(self):
        for n in range(0, 3):
            widgets.tweet_text_var[n].set(get_tweet.tweet_list[n].get("text"))


def retweet(event):
    print(get_tweet.tweet_list)


root = tk.Tk()
widgets = Widgets()
get_tweet = GetTweet()
populate_variable = PopulateVariables()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out:

By changing the Bind to :

```
self.label_list[x].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, ref=x: retweet(ref))
```

I can get the relevant ID from the "retweet" function by calling :

```
def retweet(ref):
    print(get_tweet.tweet_list[ref].get("id"))
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class GetTweet:

    def __init__(self):

        self.tweet_list = []
        self.tweet1 = {"id": 1, "text": "tweet1"}
        self.tweet2 = {"id": 2, "text": "tweet2"}
        self.tweet3 = {"id": 3, "text": "tweet3"}
        self.tweet_list.extend([self.tweet1, self.tweet2, self.tweet3])


class Widgets:

    def __init__(self):

        self.label_list = []
        self.tweet_text_var = []

        x = 0
        for n in range(0, 6, 2):

            self.tweet_text_var.append(tk.StringVar())
            self.tweet_text = ttk.Label(root, 
                                        textvariable=self.tweet_text_var[x])
            self.tweet_text.grid(column=0, row=n)
            self.label_list.append(object)
            self.label_list[x] = ttk.Label(text="Retweet", cursor="hand2")
            self.label_list[x].grid(column=0, row=n+1)
            self.label_list[x].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, ref=x: 
                                    retweet(ref))

            x += 1


class PopulateVariables:

    def __init__(self):
        for n in range(0, 3):
          widgets.tweet_text_var[n].set(get_tweet.tweet_list[n].get("text"))


def retweet(ref):
    print(get_tweet.tweet_list[ref].get("id"))



root = tk.Tk()
widgets = Widgets()
get_tweet = GetTweet()
populate_variable = PopulateVariables()
root.mainloop()
```